# Normalize a collection of WAVS in an homogenous way without loosing a bit of dynamic range

Tags: sound, daw, dynamics, dynamic-range

I ripped all my CDs of a band, and would like to do a loseless flac compilation. The degree of volume and compression is different in every album.

What's the easiest way to normalize by RMS a collection of WAVs without loosing Dynamic Range? Is there any software that calculates the averages and peaks of every song and normalizes between them considering compression?

I would like to do it in the less destructive possible way

Comment: Seems like this question https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/37142/how-to-ensure-uniform-sound-levels-in-multiple-wav-files

Comment: You need to lower the volume of the loudest tracks, instead of increasing the volume of the quietest ones. That’s all you need to do.

Comment: I always use the GNU tool normalize (http://normalize.nongnu.org/), which does this by default.